# CodeIgniter module loading creates path clash with local classes?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

Using CodeIgniter, from a controller (application/controllers/home.php), observe the line:

```
$this->load->library(array('account/authentication'))
```

AFAIK, this will:

1. Load 'authentication.php' from
   application/modules/account/libraries/authentication.php
2. Load 'authentication.php' from application/libraries/account/authentication.php

So, what if both exist? Experimenting, it seemed like CI looks for the first one, and if no such exists, it loads the second one. Isn't that kind of weird behavior?? The two files might have nothing to do with each other.

Isn't there a way of unambiguously declaring if you are referring to a local file or to a module file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no default directory `application/modules` and I can't find any reference for it in CI's docs and source.
I would say that CI's behavior is according to no.2
And indeed taking a closer look at CI's loader ([system/core/Loader.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php)) reveals the following:

1. We start at function ['library'](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L199)
2. Which calls function ['_ci_load_class'](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L901)

'_ci_load_class' disassembles the library name you passed into two parts: subdir and class name.

First it looks for the class in `libraries/subdir/class`. If it finds it - good, it loads it.
If the class was not found there, it looks for it in some other predefined pathes ([`$this->_ci_library_paths`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L61)).
If the library is still not found, it makes a last attempt and looks for it in `libraries/class/class`.

The only thing I can think of, is that you have defined a custom library path which points to a `modules` directory.  But even then, CI should look for the library in `modules/libraries/account/authentication.php`.

**Edit:**
I just noticed you tagged your question with `hmvc`, which **does** use a `modules` directory.
Unfortunately, I have no experience with it.
I would (obviously) assume this what causes the behavior you described.